# How to using Timer in c# to hovering button?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, kinect, xna-4.0

I want to make hovering button in my game. Because when my cursor touch the button it will go to another screen immediately. I don't like this so much. I use xna 4.0 with visual studio 2010 to make this project. (use kinect without wpf)

How to use timer in this case ? Please help me

```
if (Hand.contian(Button) && holdtime == targetHoldtime)
{

}
```

Comment: do you want to avoid clicking? Because you should go to the other windows when you click the mouse

Comment: @Blau yes. I want to make hovering button like this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=4-Qr9lOwGnU but I don't use wpf how can I gonna make this?

Comment: @Blau Yes, I use xna.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to manage time by yourself based in elapsed time per frame:

```
 ft = GameTime.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;  // Xna
 ft= 1/30f;  // 30fps
```

And can be done in similar way to this:

```
 class Button {
     public float Duration = 1; // One second
     public Rectangle Bounds;   // Button boundaries
     public float Progress { get{ return Elapsed/Duration; } }
     float Elapsed = 0;

     public void Update(float ft) {
          if (Bounds.Contains( HandPosition ))
          {
               if (Elapsed<Duration) {
                   Elapsed += ft;
                   if (Elapsed>Duration) {
                       Elapsed = Duration;
                       OnClick();
                   }
               }
          } else {
             Elapsed = 0;
          }
     }      
 }
```

Comment: if i already have Button class. Can I use this into my method Button_click.

Answer (score 0):

I would first suggest that you look through the SDK documentation and the built in [`KinectInteraction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn188674.aspx) controls.  They may provide you with what you are looking for.  Most notably SDK 1.7 removed that "HoverDwell" button in favor of a "press" action, which is a more natural interaction in a gesture system.  You may want to look at using that motion instead.

If you truly desire a "click on hover" type action, you can look at the code in SDK 1.6 for an example.  Several examples are available online at the [Kinect for Windows CodePlex](http://kinectforwindows.codeplex.com/) repository.  The specific control example you are looking for is in the "BasicInteraction-WPF" project, and is called [`HoverDwellButton`](http://kinectforwindows.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#v1.x/ToolkitSamples1.6.0/C#/BasicInteractions-WPF/Controls/HoverDwellButton.cs).

The "button" is actually a `ContentControl` which means you can place any content in there to make it a button.  It can be a simple image, or a complex `Grid`.  It has all the hooks to fire events when the timer on your hover goes off.

There is a decent amount of complexity in this control, which is what makes it work for a wide range of applications.  At the core of the interaction is a simple `DispatcherTimer`.

```
private void OnPreviewHandEnter(object sender, HandInputEventArgs args)
{
    if (this.trackedHandHovers.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Hand.Equals(args.Hand)) == null)
    {

        // additional logic removed for answer sanity

        var timer = new HandHoverTimer(DispatcherPriority.Normal, this.Dispatcher);
        timer.Hand = args.Hand;

        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Settings.Default.SelectionTime);
        timer.Tick += (o, s) => { this.InvokeHoverClick(args.Hand); };
        this.trackedHandHovers.Add(timer);
        timer.Start();
    }

    args.Handled = true;
}
```

Notice that the `Tick` event is calling `InvokeHoverClick`, which (in part) reads as follows:

```
public void InvokeHoverClick(HandPosition hand)
{

    // additional logic removed for answer sanity

    var t = new DispatcherTimer();
    t.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.6);

    t.Tick += (o, s) =>
                  {
                      t.Stop();
                      var clickArgs = new HandInputEventArgs(HoverClickEvent, this, hand);
                      this.RaiseEvent(clickArgs);
                      this.IsSelected = false;
                  };
    t.Start();
}
```

This now fires an *event* after a set amount of time.  This event can be capture and acted upon to your liking.

Again, I first recommend looking at the newer interactions in SDK 1.7.  If you still want a timed hover click action, check out the links above.  I used the `HoverDwellButton` to great effect in several different areas.

Comment: I use SDK beta 1.0 and I have Button_Click method and I don't know how to make hovering button because I a beginner. This is picture about my button click method. http://pic.free.in.th/id/36f0d4f3e05e9c13695f43c5dc3fd200 Please help to make this method into the hovering button. I really don't know how to coding.

Comment: I am no longer up to speed with SDK beta 1.0.  It is old.  Very old and very out of date.  Unless there is a business need for you to be using something so out of date you should be using the latest SDK.  If there is a business "need", you should be talking to you boss and convincing him/her that you shouldn't be using SDK 1.0 anymore.