# How do I do a "mouse click" with kinect?

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect

I'm in the midst of developing a kinect application.
Basically, what I have now is a simple WPF form with 3 buttons, a rightHand image and a leftHand image is tracked and is working.

I have 2 problems though.

1st Problem: Unable to move "hand" pointer to the extreme right and left.
I know this has something to do with bounding box and i'm still looking for a solution online.

2nd Problem: How do I initiate a "click" without making use of Kinect Region and the Kinect Tile Buttons? I'm looking for something similar to the video shown below

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_UqFf4KYJA

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you are looking for ?
[X-box common gestures](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/kinect/common-gestures) - Open the system menu

I think you have to use timer to check if the current positon is where you want it to be and start a counter for few secs.

Maybe this can help:
[Hovering button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18695146/how-to-using-timer-in-c-sharp-to-hovering-button)

Comment: I did more research and found out what I really want is the Hover Button by Coding4Fun. Too bad there isn't proper documentation and tutorials for the latest SDK. There are some tutorials but the SDK used and the microsoft.samples.kinect.wpfviewers used was very old.